# Android Studio 3.5 updating issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I am  having trouble  updating My  Android Studio To Version 3.5:

[image]

Is there anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: I think  I got the Same Window During the Process. But there was an option to Continue

Comment: just uninstall and install again i guess